# How to create Http multipart [multipart/form-data] with NO part names

Tags: java, httprequest, multipartform-data, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpclient-5.x

How can i create an HTTP multipart/form-data

Where wach part have no name?

** Example with attachment:

`

--boundry_root_111111111111

Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
"myJson": "Data1"
}

--boundry_root_111111111111

Content-type: Message/CPIM

From: A
Date: 2023-01-01
To: B

Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-length: 10

MyTextHere MyTextHere MyTextHere MyTextHere

Content-type: multipart/related;boundary="boundary222222"
--boundary222222
Content-ID:0
Content-Type:image/jpeg;Name="202020.jpg"
Content-Disposition:Attachment;Filename="202020.jpg"
Content-Location:202020.jpg
Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64

FileDataBase64_FileDataBase64_FileDataBase64_FileDataBase64_FileDataBase64_FileDataBase64
FileDataBase64_FileDataBase64_FileDataBase64_FileDataBase64_FileDataBase64_FileDataBase64

--boundary222222
--boundry_root_111111111111`

Tried RestAssured
Apache Httpclient

both failed,
Apache returned error when body part name was empty ,Restassured added default part name

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.